# SignInManager on remote instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a .net core 2.0 app with user authentications. Works just fine. 
I want to be able to connect multiple instances of external WebAPI and Web Apps to connect to a centralized (single) instance of the first app as an authentication and authorization point. This enables me to have a single point of management and configuration for tokens.
The AccountController implements:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
...
```

This calls the SignInManager, which is provided through DI, as created in Startup.Configure. 
So, it seems like I want a remote instance of the SignInManager to be supplied through DI. Yes, I could simply point the db connection string to the database instance, but that just seems to violate separation of concerns, as well as creating redundant code in each of the other instances.
So, how is this supported?
Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you want to use a seperate identity provider such as Azure AD B2C for this. Each web app then simply authenticates users off that app. Azure AD will handle token generation, expiration, claims, etc. for you.

Comment: What you're describing here, a remote service that handles authenticating and managing users on behalf of multiple applications is exactly what OAuth is designed to address.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcLaFleur. I should have included that this is an on-prem instance. I may investigate, though. OAuth seemed too heavy, but I will look around again to see if I can find an example closer to the architecture I am expecting. Most that I located had an external OAuth provider. Which I am trying to avoid....